# A resolution error

Tags: resolution

i installed ubuntu 12.10 but it only shows 1024X768 resolution but the resulution of my monitor is 1600X900
how can i set the real resolution on ubuntu 12.10

monitor: SAMSUNG SYNCMASTER B2030
graphics card: INTEL HD2000
processor: INTEL I3-2100
ram: SIMMTRONICS 2X2 = 4GB RAM
Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my blog post, [here](http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/04/ubuntu-screen-custom-resolution.html), suggests

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VBOX0 "1600x900_60.00"
sudo xrandr --output VBOX0 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
```

1. First command creates a new mode with resolution 1600x900
2. Second command makes it available for use, with display (in this example VBOX0)
3. Third command selects the newly added mode as the display resolution for the specified display

Comment: i will test this soon
is this will work on ubuntu 13.4.......
thanks in advance

Comment: nice blog man really liked it

Comment: Thanks :) I use 13.04 and it works for me :) Please mark this as answer, it works for you too....

Comment: thanks alot once again u r really helpfull to me thanks again

Comment: hey brother
when use your command on ubuntu 13.04
there are some result pls see it in my pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/ajn9UjJ7

Comment: Looks like you are missing 908 in the first command...

Comment: ohh 
thanks for pointing me

i will try again
btw i was on ubuntu 13.04 live mode